# Measuring average time taken for context switch

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pthreads, pipe

I am trying to measure the time taken for a context switch using pipes and threads, however I noticed that when I ran my code, it was simply printing the prior initialized value of `avg` which is 0. My code is below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<time.h>

int fd[2];
int n = 0;
int avg = 0;
struct timespec tv;

void * writeThread()
{
        long now = 0;
        for(n=100000;n>0;n--)
        {
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&tv);
                now = tv.tv_nsec;
                write(fd[1],(void*)&now,sizeof(now));

                usleep(1000);
        }
        return 0;
}

void * readThread()
{
        long now = 0;
        for(n=100000;n>0;n--)
        {
                int time = read(fd[0],(void*)&now,sizeof(now));
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&tv);
                now = tv.tv_nsec;
                int switchTime = now - time;
                avg = avg + switchTime;
        }
        avg = avg/1000;
        printf("%d",avg);
        return 0;
}




int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

        pthread_t tid1,tid2;

        pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,writeThread,NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,readThread,NULL);
/*      pthread_join(tid1,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid2,NULL);
*/
        printf("%d",avg);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you using a global now? Seems to me its just asking for a threading disaster given your using an unlocked global variable for the core logic of your system.

Comment: I figured it didn't make a difference, but changed that now.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your fd[] array doesn't seem to be initialized.   You're also sharing the global variable 'tv' without protection.  Your main is printing out the average without waiting for the two threads to  complete.

Comment: your time variable is reading in the number of blocks of data that have been read and then you are using it to calculate the switching time. You read the prev time into now then get the new time and overwrite now with it.